# How to check if my Stripe account is in Test Mode?

Tags: php, cakephp, stripe-payments, cakephp-1.3

I'm integrating Stripe into a site built on a CakePHP 1.3 installation and am using the Stripe AIP integrated into CakePHP as a simple Component. I have it working pretty well so far but would like to have my code sense if the Stripe account is in test mode and then use the appropriate API key.

Is there a flag somewhere in the Stripe API that look at? Or am I just going about this the wrong way and need to think about this differently? I'm open to guidance on the whole Stripe/CakePHP integration. It's very different than PayPal and I'm liking it a lot so far.

Comment: If you use the test API key, then your request is in test mode. You may want to go through https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys.

Comment: I have both keys in my code and can use both to successfully process charges. I would like my code to recognize when I put Stripe into test mode so I don't have to make that change at both ends. I want mine to be smart enough to auto switch.

Comment: what do you mean by making that `change at both ends` - what does `both ends` refer to? and where do you `put Stripe into test mode`?

Comment: I was under the impression that I had to change the slider in the Stripe website's interface as well as using the test API key. The answer below explains it very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the mode in the Stripe Dashboard doesn't enable/disable test mode. Both live mode and test mode are active at the same time. You choose which mode you interact with by using either the test API key or "live" API key.

You can verify it by enabling "live" mode in Stripe dashboard, and then using "test" API key to create a PaymentIntent. When you switch back to "test" mode in Stripe dashboard, the PaymentIntent you just created will be there.

Comment: That makes sense! I was under the impression that setting the "Test Mode" slider in the Stripe website changed the mode there. It's just changing the view. The API key is what controls the actual charge.  Thank you!